# Are bandsaw restoration questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently purchased a second hand 14 inch bandsaw which is in need of much work before I can start using it. I have several questions I'd like to ask about how to repair/restore certain parts of the bandsaw. Are these types of questions on topic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you submit each question individually and can provide enough detail about the issues regarding that part without the question becoming too esoteric, it would be on-topic.  Be sure to also search for similar questions first, as we may already have existing questions which cover more general topics such as rust removal and bandsaw tune-up.

Note that questions about specific vendors or products may be considered off-topic if it seems like you are asking for product recommendations, but you may ask more generally for tips on how to locate replacement parts, if you are having trouble finding a source.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep my questions focused.